# Particle System: How do fix this orientation problem?

Tags: particles

[image]

Im trying to use the particle system to create a roof. I'm getting this thing where the rotation of the objects kind of vary? I want all the tiles to be oriented flat and to rotated exactly as the object. How do I fix this? Also, I'm pretty new to Blender and still trying to learn. Thanks!

Comment: if you provide your blend file i will look at it...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using instances on faces for this task.

[image]

instances on faces duplicates child objects on every face of the model